# Visualize polyhedron with colored edges

Tags: visualization, paraview, ply-file-format

I want to visualize a 3D polyhedron which consists of polygons (not always triangles) and in which all parts are coloured: facets, edges and vertices.
Is it possible to do that in some polyhedron format?
Stanford PLY format support edge colours, but I failed to find the visualization program that supports edges colouring in PLY format. For example, Paraview can color facets, but it can't color edges even if the input PLY file contains colored edges.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option. After a long investigation I have found no way to color edges in paraview. The only workaround is to create additional colored thin facets near the edges that are needed to be colored.